# JPA - how to map composite keys hierarchy

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a db structure similar to this on the picture
[image]

table `questions` has composite primary key (id, cate_id), where cate_id is foreign key to categories(cate_id)
table `answers` has composite primary key (id, question_id), where question_id is foreign key to questions(id)

from data perspective it looks like this:
CATEGORIES

| cate_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | Cat 1 |
| C2 | Cat 2 |

QUESTIONS

| id | cate_id | question |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 | C1 | what ? |
| Q2 | C1 | why ? |
| Q1 | C2 | when ? |
| Q2 | C2 | who ? |

ANSWERS

| id | question_id | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Q1 | aaa |
| A2 | Q1 | bbb |
| A1 | Q2 | ccc |
| A2 | Q2 | ddd |

Now I'm trying to map it to JPA model:
the category entity is the simplest:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "cate_id")
    private Long id;
...
}
```

now I'm adding the QuestionId to reflect the composite key and Question entity:

```
@Embeddable
public class QuestionId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "cate_id")
    private Long categoryId;
//constructors, hashCode, equals, etc
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {

    @EmbeddedId
    private QuestionId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId(value = "categoryId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "cate_id")
    private Category category;
}
```

all good so far

the problem starts when I try to add next level: the Answers entity

```
@Embeddable
public class AnswerId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "question_id")
    private Long questionId;
//constructors, hashCode, equals, etc
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "answers")
public class Answer {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AnswerId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId(value = "questionId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Question question;
}
```

After creating the Answer entity I'm receiving this error on application startup
`Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to find column reference in the @MapsId mapping: cate_id`
For me it looks like the Answer entity needs access to Categories which makes no sense I guess.
And it has nothing to do with existing database configuration because I have the same result on H2 in-memory db and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

any suggestions will be more than welcome
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that my DB model makes no sense.
The question in the Answers table is not unique accross the system, so there are two ways of solving it:

- add a category_id reference to answers table (which is what JPA is
  complaining about) 
  or
- make the question_id unique in the system through some sequence generator or anything else